# Problems in a little Spider code in Python3

Tags: python, web-crawler

I was trying to write a spider to get some information from [Steam's top-sellers](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers) list.
But there's some problems with my code.
I think it is about the '`re`' module, because I couldn't print those codes inside the `for` loop. And running the code, it always writes "`[]`" to the file I provided.

```
def getDetail(self, url):
    source = self.getSource(url)
    pattern = re.compile('<div class="col search_name ellipsis"><span class="title">(.*?)</span>', re.S)
    items = re.findall(pattern, source)
    print(re.findall(pattern, source))
    number = 1
    for item in items:
        print('Crawling No.%d game' % number)
        print('Name: %s' % item[0])
        number += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return items
```

And here's my whole code.

```
import requests
import re
import time


class Spider(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.siteURL = 'http://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers'

    def getSource(self, url):
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                 'Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'
        headers = {'User_agent': user_agent}
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        return r.text

    def getDetail(self, url):
        source = self.getSource(url)
        pattern = re.compile('<div class="col search_name ellipsis"><span class="title">(.*?)</span>', re.S)
        items = re.findall(pattern, source)
        print(re.findall(pattern, source))
        number = 1
        for item in items:
            print('Crawling No.%d game' % number)
            print('Name: %s' % item[0])
            number += 1
            time.sleep(0.1)
        return items

    def saveDetail(self):
        data = str(self.getDetail(self.siteURL))
        fileName = 'SteamTopseller.txt'
        f = open(fileName, 'wb')
        f.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
        print('Successfully written!')
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spider = Spider()
    spider.saveDetail()
```

Please help me solve this little problem, thanks!
By the way, I code in python3.

Answer (score 0):

......

#### re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)

Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

Therefore, if there is not matches in string, it returns a empty list, as [].

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

To skip the "[]", you may code as

```
items = re.findall(pattern, source)
if items:
    print(items)
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

To remove the newline character

```
def getDetail(self, url):
    source = self.getSource(url).replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "")
```

Comment: But it should have at least one match according to the  **steam** webpage. I've tried your advice but it still printed "[]". Is there anything wrong I did on the "re.compile" thing?

Comment: Because there are newline character from the page source, you have to remove them first for the `re` module. Otherwise, you should try using `bs4`, `Beautiful Soup` module, for pulling the lxml data.

Comment: It worked. I thought **re.S** would have done that. Anyway, thank you for your help.